# Why does SuperCam need a combination of lasers?

Tags: perseverance, supercam

In the video on the [NASA website](https://mars.nasa.gov/resources/25970/mars-report-update-on-nasas-perseverance-rover-supercam-instrument-june-10-2021/), the speaker says that in SuperCam,

> we use a combination of lasers

Why does the SuperCam need multiple lasers? Did ChemCam also have several lasers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SuperCam has an infrared laser with a wavelength of 1064-nm and a green laser with 532 nm.

They are used for two different methods of spectroscopy.

> Laser-induced breakdown spectroscopy (LIBS) is a type of atomic
> emission spectroscopy which uses a highly energetic laser pulse as the
> excitation source. The laser is focused to form a plasma, which
> atomizes and excites samples.

LIBS uses the 1064 nm laser to detect atoms.

> Raman spectroscopy is a spectroscopic technique typically used to
> determine vibrational modes of molecules, although rotational and
> other low-frequency modes of systems may also be observed.[1] Raman
> spectroscopy is commonly used in chemistry to provide a structural
> fingerprint by which molecules can be identified.

The Raman spectroscopy uses the 532 nm laser to detect molecules.

ChemCam used only LIBS.

Quotes from Wikipedia.

Comment: 1064 nm is *infrared*, not *red*.  Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: My guess is that there is just one (laser)diode-pumped Nd:YAG laser at 1064 nm and the 532 nm is a frequency-doubled beam.  Same thing that was in the old green laser pointers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode-pumped_solid-state_laser#Common_DPSSL_processes